# How to check Envelope ID exists in DocuSign using API

Tags: docusignapi

Is the way we can check whether the envelope id exists or not in DocuSign using DocuSign API

Comment: Do you want to check if envelope exists in your account or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check envelopeIds in your account, then there are two ways of doing it,

a. First way is, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus/#/definitions/envelopeIdsRequest

PUT https://{{EnvironmentVal}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{AccountIdVal}}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body

Body -

{
    "envelopeIds": [
        "53dd78a1-2795-4d0b-b377-69d139ecc7cd",
        "56aa2169-f027-40bd-b3ee-7b3c99272e93",
        "5e046e10-6e96-44e1-8980-b687153d90bf"
    ]
}

Response will have those envelopeIds which are in system and the user has access to.

b. Second way is, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/

If envelope does not exist then it will throw 404 error with below message,

{
    "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_DOES_NOT_EXIST",
    "message": "The envelope specified either does not exist or you have no rights to it."
}

In first way no error is thrown and you can send multiple envelopes in a single call.